# Firebase crashlytics not uploading dysm automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I'm having problem when migrating to firebase crashlytics from fabric with the automatic upload of dysm. Ever since i migrated to firebase the automatic upload isn't working.

I have already tried updating to the lates firebase version, Adding the dwarf with dysm file, reinstal crashlytics and also with the manual script but the script never finishes.(this script https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports). Is there a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

When migrating from Fabric, you only need to follow the [migration](https://fabric.io/firebase_migration) process (aka: linking your Fabric app to your Firebase project) but no other changes to your app are needed like mentioned in the "Today" section of the road map: https://get.fabric.io/roadmap#transition-plan

If you made any changes like removing the Fabric API Key and/or upgrading the Crashlytics SDK to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK, then you need to get back to the previous configuration, like the one shown here: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install After that, you should be able to upload the dSYMs without issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to upload the DSYM's only when releasing a build than add the following code to your scheme archive post actions:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/[FOLDER WITH THE GOOGLE PLIST]/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Please replace **[FOLDER WITH THE GOOGLE PLIST]** with you actual path

[image]

That will run the crashlytics upload_symbols script that comes with their POD

If you would like to upload on each build than create a new run script in the build phases and add the same code there.